# Replace nested JavaScript Object data item with dynamically created path?

Tags: javascript, json

I've got this JSON data object (example):

```
let obj = [
  {
    test0: [ 
      {testA: 'ContentA' },
      {testB: 'ContenB'}
    ] 
  }
];
```

I'd like to replace the value of key 'testB' dynamically. I.e. I need to be able to address any item in the object and replace ist.

Here's what I am doing so far:

Therefore I programmatically generate a mixed key/index path to address the target object and it looks like this (in array form):

```
let path = [0,'\'test0\'',1,'\'testB\''];
```

In order to put this in an executable form which does the actual replacement, I convert path to JavaScript code and run it with eval. Like this:

```
let newText = 'ContentB';
eval(`obj[${path.join('][')}]=\'${newText}\'`);
```

Eval executes this code literal:

```
obj[0]['test0'][1]['testB'] = 'ContentB'
```

This works, but if possible, I'd like to know if there's an alternative way which works without using "eval".

Comment: NB/ this has nothing to do with JSON. Please check out the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I apologize. I have read the description and I admit it's not a JSON problem but a javascript Object problem. I will update the title accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive function and pass it the property path as an array of properties, like this:

```js
function setDeepValue(obj, [prop, ...path], value) {
    if (!path.length) {
        obj[prop] = value; 
    } else {
        if (!(prop in obj)) obj[prop] = {};
        setDeepValue(obj[prop], path, value);
    }
}

// Example:
const arr = [{
    test0: [ 
        { testA: 'ContentA' },
        { testB: 'ContenB' }
    ]
}];
  
setDeepValue(arr, [0, "test0", 1, "testB"], "ContentB");

console.log(arr);
```

If you are OK with using a library, you could use Lodash, which has  [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) and the more flexible [`_.setWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#setWith) to do this.

Comment: I don't know, if I have misread your answer, but I am missing the part, where the new value is being _set_.

Comment: Updated to *set* a value.